# Creating a Welcome Bot Using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have been moderating a telegram group for some time and I have had no issues using the python-telegram-bot package. I actually love it. However, I can't seem to get a functioning "Welcome Message" for when new users join.

Right now, I have tried structuring the function like I do with my command and message handlers:

```
def welcome(update,context):
    #name = from_user.username
    #update.message.reply_text("""Welcome blah blah blah to the group!""")
```

and then calling it it my main function like so:

```
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(ChatMemberHandler(welcome, ChatMemberHandler.CHAT_MEMBER))
updater.start_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)
updater.idle()
```

But am getting an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply_text'

So I guess the "member joined the group" pop up is not considered a message. But I dont know how to extract that event or which handler to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You're trying to reply to the `update.message` when there's no `message` in `update`. Review the documentation, you're using the wrong parameter. It should be something other than `message`.

Comment: @thethiny do you have any idea what it would be? Im sorry this is my first time building a telegram bot. i havent dealt with anything other than a message. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As thethiny already pointed out, chatmember updates have no associated message: `update.message` will be `None`, while `update.chat_member` will be an instance of `ChatMemberUpdated`. Note that `Message.reply_text` is just a shortcut for `Bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, ...)`, so as long as you have the `chat_id` you can just use e.g. `context.bot.send_message` - and you can get that `chat_id` from `ChatMemberUpdated.chat`. In fact, you can still use PTBs shortcuts, e.g. `update.effective_chat.send_message`.

Please check out the docs of

- `ChatMemberUpdated` ([official](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated) and [PTB](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chatmemberupdated.html))
- [`Update.effective_chat`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html#telegram.Update.effective_chat)
- [`Chat.send_message`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chat.html#telegram.Chat.send_message)

as well as the [`chatmemberbot.py` example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/chatmemberbot.py) provided by PTB.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: absolutely beautiful explanation! thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help. If I could solve your problem, please consider marking my answer as accepted answer :)